# Add multiple condition in one cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to add multiple conditions in one cell

I'm doing this:

```
=SI(OU(A3=$A$1;A3>$A$1);"OK");SI(ET(A3<$A$1;B3<>0);"Nope");SI(OU(B3=0;B3="");"SO")
```

I don't understand where is my problem ?

[image]

Someone can explain me

Comment: please translate the formula into English.  The answer you will get will be in English and we need to know that you know how to translate the formula.  If you do not want to or cannot translate then please visit the site for your native language: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ or https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: `=IF(A3>=$A$1,"OK",IF(--B3<>0,"Nope","SO"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `IF` statement needs a TRUE and FALSE value for a condition. Your parentheses are in the wrong spots; you have to nest the IFS like this:

`=SI(OU(A3=$A$1;A3>$A$1);"OK";SI(ET(A3<$A$1;B3<>0);"Nope";SI(OU(B3=0;B3="");"SO";"Omelet du fromage")))`

Or in English:

`=IF(OR(A3=$A$1;A3>$A$1);"OK";IF(AND(A3<$A$1;B3<>0);"Nope";IF(OR(B3=0;B3="");"SO";"Omelet du fromage")))`

Comment: So in English that will be "Cheese omelette"...

Answer (score 0):

My first step would be to reduce the formula by not using the OR() (OU()) like so:

```
=if(A3>=A1,"OK","No")
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you are trying to add multiple conditions in an IF condition, I find that it helps to first write down the conditions and then replace them with the cell addresses to help simplify the placement of braces.

```
=IF (Condition 1, Output if True, Output if False)
```

For every additional condition check, you can add the same code in the respective output place and continue. By following this template you can easily solve this without getting any error involving parantheses.

Your rectified code should be:

```
=IF(OR(A3=$A$1,A3>$A$1),"OK",IF(AND(A3<$A$1,B3<>0),"Nope",IF(OR(B3=0;B3=""),"SO","Omelet du fromage")))
```

Comment: Semicolons will work depending on your locale